# Web browser control hangs my application

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a button and a web browser control on my WinForms application. When I click on a button it fires up a browser, but until page is loaded my application hangs even though I use a separate thread for browser control.

How can I handle it so my application doesn't hang while page gets loaded?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread mythread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(go));    
    mythread.IsBackground = true;
    mythread.Name = "mythread";
    mythread.Start();
}

void go() 
{ 
    webBrowser1.Navigate("google.com"); 
}
```

Comment: Don't execute `go` in thread.

Comment: Can you please describe which web browser control did you use, maybe include a link so people quickly get an idea about it?

Comment: web browser that include in vs 2010 tool box

Comment: You can't cheat a single-threaded component like WebBrowser.  COM makes sure that the method gets executed on the thread that you created it on.

Comment: you could always try this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610197/async-await-implementation-of-webbrowser-class-for-net

Comment: It's not quite correct to say that the WebBrowser control is "single-threaded", but it's absolutely true that you need to keep your interactions with it on the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, the issue was resolved by using dispatcher. Using Background worker would throw you an error since you are trying in code behind.

Try the below in button click.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => { go(); }));
```

Namespace for the above is System.Threading

Comment: In WinForms one needs to use Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher instead. Then it works at least in the happy day scenario (didn't find a way to provoke network problem so far).

Answer (score 0):

After the .navigate method, do this...

```
Do
Sleep 100
Doevents
Loop until webbrowser1.busy = true and webbrowser1.readystate = 4
```

This should sort at thread out, .busy could be .isbusy on your version of wb control, look out my other web browser related answers if you want to implement a proper, more detailed method on pausing execution until web browser is truly done loading a webpage.

Ket me know how it works out for you and if I can be of any further help.