# WebBrowser run on same thread

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I need to prevent WebBrowser.Navigate() run on the same thread because I need the process to be certain order.

I came across [Async/Await implementation of WebBrowser class for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610197/async-await-implementation-of-webbrowser-class-for-net) which uses async/await implementation but I have to use .net 3.5 which doesn't support it.

Anyone know of any alternative methods?

Comment: You cannot prevent it from running on the same thread, WebBrowser is a single-threaded COM object.  The simple alternative to async/await is a state machine.  Or run everything on a separate thread, as [shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4271581/17034).

Comment: If you can't use `async`/`await`, perhaps you can use `IEnumerable`/`yield`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22296644/1768303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting a flag on the main form. Then there is a thread.sleep until the flag is reset.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your requirements, you can use the `WebBrowser` component's `DocumentCompleted` event in the following way:

```
webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(Loaded);
webBrowser.Navigate(...);

...

void Loaded(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff that needs to be run after the page is loaded
}
```